# What do you call someone who censors another person?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

What do you call someone who inappropriately censors another person?

Is there any specific word for someone who derives pleasure out of censoring another person?

To use it in an example: *[Word] like him like to censor what other people have to say by deleting their posts.*  (And let's assume that there is nothing offensive or inappropriate in the deleted posts.)

Note that I'm just looking for a general term for a lecture I am presenting; my request is *not* specific to any single incident.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific on how the person censors others? Their grammar? Their accents? Their behavior? Please note the following is the strict rule of this community. *Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered*. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @Rathony Editing...

Comment: @Rathony Does that work?

Comment: Well, it is better than before obviously. But what post and where? On Stack Exchange?

Comment: @Rathony Would it be a different word if it were on Stack Exchange versus somewhere else?

Comment: It's called a "censor" - a person who examines books, movies, letters, etc., and removes things that are considered to be offensive, immoral, harmful to society, etc.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard Well, it is better to be more specific than not. I also thought about "censor", but the question is would (s)he derive pleasure from doing that? I don't know. Your question is not easy.

Comment: @Rathony I made a couple more improvements and amplifications.  "Your question is not easy." = Must be a good question then!  :-)

Comment: I think the word depends on the motivation. *Bigot* would fit, for example, but wouldn't be appropriate in all cases.

Comment: I can't think of single word for inappropriate censorship, I suppose you could just add an adjective to censor, like abusive or unjustified.

Comment: You might say that the person is *censorious*.

Answer (score 2):

Only phrase (not a single word) that I can think of is "[malicious](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/malicious) editor" who does malicious edit. Malicious means

> having or showing a desire to cause harm to another person : having or
>   showing malice

[Merriam Webster]

I found one website which defines [malicious edits](http://lostgirl.wikia.com/wiki/Lost_Girl_Wiki:Vandalism_%C2%B7_Malicious_edits_%C2%B7_Spam_%C2%B7_Harassment_(Policy)) as

> **unwarranted removal of content**;  renaming articles without
>   justification;  purposefully adding incorrect or false information to
>   articles;  editing articles to promote a particular view and/or for
>   the sake of a personal agenda;  editing other Users' comments to
>   substantially change their meaning;  adding nonsense to a page.
>
> Malicious edits also involve:  making an offensive  Edit Summary  in
>   an attempt to leave a mark that cannot be easily expunged from a
>   page's history record;  uploading or using material in ways that
>   violate copyright policy after having been warned.

and malicious editor as:

> Any User, registered or anonymous, who persists in making edits or
>   create new pages that contradict the format, style, and standards of
>   the Lost Girl Wiki will be considered a malicious editor.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a phrase rather than a single word, and suggest [Petty Tyrant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petty_tyranny)

> It is a pejorative term, that carries with it a sense of authority
>   that was gained, or is used, in an unfair or capricious manner.

Answer (score 1):

---

Such a person would be a **suppressor** (noun)

[Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/suppressor)

> a thing or person that suppresses somebody/something

*suppress* meaning to:

> 1 ~ to put an end to the activities of (a person, body of persons, etc.)
>
> 2 ~ to do away with by or as by authority; abolish; stop (a practice, custom, etc.)
>
> 4 ~ to withhold from disclosure or publication (truth, evidence, a book, names, etc.)

[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/suppress)

---

*Suppressor* would be better than *censor* here because the person who *suppresses* something is not only *censoring* it but is also acting from a position of *authority*.

---